# too much pathinfo using buildURL

Tags: coldfusion, routes, fw1

I try to get an impression how to build a REST-API using `FW/1` version 4.
I set this in my `Application.cfc`:

```
<cfset variables.framework.routes = [
    { "$GET/persons/:id/$" = "/persons/show/id/:id" }
]>
```

My controller method

```
<cffunction name="show">
    <cfargument name="rc" type="struct" required="true">

    <cfset local.strURL = variables.fw.buildURL(
        action = 'persons.show',
        queryString = 'id=123'
    )>

    <cfset variables.fw.renderData().data( { strURL = local.strURL } ).type( "json" )>
</cffunction>
```

I call `/persons/123` and get this output:

```
{"URL":"/persons/show/id/123"}
```

I don't like the `/show/` pathinfo in this generated URL. It's not part of the URL I requested in the browser (or via AJAX etc.). Is there a way to get rid of this in the generated URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a functionality in FW/1. This was considered in 2012, but was rejected.

See: https://github.com/framework-one/fw1/issues/145

The core issue was (and is) according to Sean Corfield:

> Interesting idea but I think you'll find that, in general, routes =>
>   URLs is actually a many-to-one mapping so you can't reliably go
>   backwards from URLs (actions / params) to a unique route. I've talked
>   that over a few times with people and so far no one has managed to
>   come up with a mapping that works in all cases.